# Creating a queue for unrootable messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

I have several Java Clients sending messages publishing to direct exchange.

I want each of the clients to publish using their ID as a routing key (or as a header I can change to a headers exchange). If there's a queue bound using that rooting key it will publish to it else it will publish to a global queue.

So my question is, is it possible to have a queue that receives messages from the clients whom rooting key/header cannot be rooted to any of the queues ? Something which looks like a default queue.

Thanks.

Comment: What is **rooting** key? Did you mean **routing** key?

Comment: yes sorry meant routing key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using RabbitMQ [Alternative exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html)